# Force all http traffic to https except one URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am redirecting all traffic to my site to https connection.

But I'm having an issue with an API page which uses the http protocol, so users using the uploading API are unable to upload because the https is affecting the entire site. I have tried several htaccess rules, but it seems most of the questions asked are opposite to what I need.

Here is the htaccess rule I use for forcing all traffic to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Let's assume the url is http://example.com/uploading-api.php

I want to force https on site in exception of uploading-api.php. In this case the other pages must be accessed with https on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^uploading-api\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^uploading-api\.php http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I just tried it, but still im able to access uploading-api.php on https, I would like to be able to access it on http only if possible

Comment: As per this rule even if you use `https` it will be redirected to `http`. Make sure these 2 are first rules and you test in a new browser.